Helm-bookmark suddenly slow (profiler report attached)
Recently I must wait ~10 seconds for helm-bookmarks to appear.
Does somebody discover anything helpful in the cpu profiler report?
     456  80% - command-execute
     228  40%  - call-interactively
     228  40%   - funcall-interactively
     224  39%    - helm-filtered-bookmarks
     224  39%     - helm
     224  39%      - apply
     224  39%       - helm
     224  39%        - apply
     224  39%         - helm-internal
     113  20%          + helm-read-from-minibuffer
     104  18%          + helm-initialize
       7   1%          + #<compiled 0x198071971901>
       3   0%    + lazy-helm/profiler-stop
       1   0%    + file-notify-handle-event
     152  26%  + autoload-do-load
      69  12% + ...
      24   4% + timer-event-handler
      10   1% + redisplay_internal (C function)
       4   0% + exwm-layout--on-echo-area-change


Deleting the latest bookmark to a non-working mounted remote drive was the solution
